# Can a Component Be in Both an FLA Library and a SWC Used by That FLA?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swc

I am working on a project with Flash CS5 and have come across a conflict similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205373/problem-using-flash-components-in-multiple-swc-files) (but I cannot use Runtime sharing), and I am wondering if there is a way around it.

I have a FLA which contains some of the standard Flash UI Components (Button, ScrollBar, etc.). These are used in various MovieClips. This FLA is exported to a SWC which is used by other FLAs.

In one of those other FLAs with the SWC included (Actionscript Settings -> Library path), everything works fine until I decide I need to place a Flash UI Component on the stage. I add this component to the FLA (let's say it's a Button), put it on the stage and build. I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@27b37ab9 to fl.controls.Button.
```

This is in reference to the Button instance in the child FLA. Flash seems unable to reconcile the two references to fl.controls.Button: the one in the SWC and the one in the FLA.

I can safely omit the Button from the child FLA's library and simply create them via Actionscript. However, it is much more convenient to position and size it on the stage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a different applicationDomain that will help with the conflicts, more info on app domains here on adobe's site:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html